# Exception "Data source name not found" while connecting to an existing DSN

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I have created an ODBC connections (both 32/64 bit) with configuration given below:

```
Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 10.00.14393

Data Source Name: ODBCMSSQL
Data Source Description: 
Server: .\SQLEXPRESS
Database: MedicalMarketting
Language: (Default)
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Prepared Statements Option: Drop temporary procedures on disconnect
Use Failover Server: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
Data Encryption: No
```

I want to connect to local MsSQL server as given in below code snippet:

```
        string connectionString = "Data Source=ODBCMSSQL;Initial Catalog=MedicalMarketting;Integrated Security=True";
        con = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            this.con.Open();
            this.tr = con.BeginTransaction();
            this.cmd.Transaction = tr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                this.RollBack();
        }
```

This throws an exception which has an error message as below:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Sorry if this was too basic, but had to post for a clue because the same configuration for different ODBC connections works perfectly.

Comment: 32bit and 64bit DSNs are separate.  You need to create one for the bitness of your program.  `c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe` is the 32bit ODBC Data source Administrator `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe` is the 64bit one (and no I didn't get those backwards :).  Also why use ODBC from C#, instead of the built-in System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Both DSNs exist and I updated the question. Btw, I'm using OdbcConnection because I'm using the same class to connect to multiple types of databases (eg :- AS400).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix to the problem by changing the connection string to,

```
string connectionString = "DSN=ODBCMSSQL";// best practice is to store this in a seperate config file.
```

In fact, other attributes specified (Initial Catalog, Integrated Security) are not ODBC connection string attributes, hence ignored. A full list of ODBC connection attributes can be found below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275047(v=bts.10).aspx